# Get rid of default formatting for outputText

Tags: visualforce, formatting, outputtext

I am trying to print out a sum of 2 Integer variables using outputText, however it appears with a different format than normal text. How can I get rid of this formatting?

```
<apex:outputText value="{0} relationships ">
    <apex:param value="{!numberOfContactRelations + numberOfAccountRelations}"/>
</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText value="({!numberOfContactRelations} contact/{!numberOfAccountRelations} account)" />
```

[image]

The second outputText looks fine, however, the first one is the one I want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that this was caused by wrapping both outputText in a pageBlockSectionItem. Solved this by wrapping it in an outputPanel

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputText value="{!numberOfContactRelations + numberOfAccountRelations} relationships "/>
        <apex:outputText value="({!numberOfContactRelations} contact/{!numberOfAccountRelations} account)" />
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```